# How to return multiple rows when compared to multiple values?

Tags: mysql, database

So my current table looks like this :

```
  |  UserID  |  QuestionID  |  GameID  |
  |  1       |  30          |  2       |
  |  1       |  30          |  3       |
  |  2       |  30          |  4       |
  |  3       |  30          |  2       |
  |  4       |  30          |  3       |
```

How would I return all the rows where the same UserID has a value for GameID 1, 2, 3 and 4? Basically trying to return all the users who have played Game 1, 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 4):

Assuming no duplicates of game id..

```
Select userID 
from table 
where gameID in (1,2,3,4) 
group by UserID
having count(GameID) = 4
```

Comment: be careful because this query will not ensure that the user has the gameid 1,2,3 and 4 it only ensures that it has 4 entries that are in 1 to 4. But if your application logic does not allow this case you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the answer correct, it might be:

```
SELECT p.* FROM poll AS p WHERE p.UserID = <your_user_id> AND p.GameID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

or you are seeking for:

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(p.GameID) FROM poll AS p WHERE p.UserID = <user_id> GROUP BY p.GameID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables are normalized and joined properly, simply use a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE colname = value1 OR colname = value2 ...
```

or use the In operator

```
WHERE colname = In (value,value...)
```

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-logical-operators.htm

Comment: This answer is equivalent to "Use SQL", therefore it's pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  UserID
FROM (
  SELECT
    UserID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(GameID ORDER BY GameID) as Games
  FROM some_table
  GROUP BY UserID
) AS baseview
WHERE Games="1,2,3,4"
```

Please understand, this is a performance killer - it creates the GROUP_CONCAT for all users.